# Why does associated object not save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby (on rails) class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relationships
  belongs_to :current_shipping_address, :class_name => "Address"
  belongs_to :subscription

  # Validators
  validates_presence_of :subscription
  validates_presence_of :current_shipping_address
end
```

I do this in a controller:

```
subscription = Subscription.new

address_info = params[:user].delete(:address) rescue {}
@address = Address.new(address_info.merge(:country => "US"))

@user = User.new(params[:user].merge(:first_name => @address.first_name, :last_name => @address.last_name))
@user.subscription = subscription
@user.current_shipping_address = @address
@user.save!
```

At this point, incredibly, I have a @user that has been saved in the database but has no current_shipping_address (despite the validation). The subscription has also been saved in the database.

The address does NOT get saved.

What am I missing here? 
1 - how does user get saved without the validation failing?
2 - why is the address not saved?

How can I alter this code so that the address gets saved (as I would expect it to)?

I am running this under ruby on rails 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have subscription and current_shipping_address saved by user in your case because, they are not simple fields in model User. You define them as model associated to User through belongs_to, I'm not sure about what you are willing to do, but if I understand correctly one way to do it is using nested attributes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relationships
  has_many :current_shipping_addresses, :class_name => "Address", :dependant => destroy
  has_many :subscriptions, :dependant => destroy


  # Nesting
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :current_shipping_addresses

end
```

After that, when you then create and save a User, a subscription and current_shipping_address are saved whith it .

More on assocations here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it what the foreign key is if you're not sticking with the standard table structure. You'll just need to add:

```
belongs_to :current_shipping_address, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => "address_id"
```

or whatever column you are using to store the address id to the address table.

This is not the recommended way of doing nested attributes though. I would recommend using a `fields_for` in your form rather than using the lines:

```
address_info = params[:user].delete(:address) rescue {}
@address = Address.new(address_info.merge(:country => "US"))
```

You can just do

<%= f.fields_for :current_shipping_address do |ff| %>
      # ... your address fields...
   <% end %>

which will then let you simply save the address when you run `@user.save!`

You can still add the `:country => "US"` beforehand with

```
params[:user][:current_shipping_address][:country] = "US"
```

and then run save. Its really up to you though.

Comment: Your comments are fair about the form structure and so on, but that doesn't actually fix the issue of why the address object is not saving (as far as I can see). I am using formtastic so unfortunately your solution doesn't apply directly to me. With your solution you can still end up with no address saved.

Comment: Oh, and the field on the user object is current_shipping_address_id, so there is not a problem with the foreign key,

Answer (score 0):

Try this way!

```
subscription = Subscription.new

address_info = params[:user].delete(:address) rescue {}

@user = User.new(params[:user].merge(:first_name => @address.first_name, :last_name => @address.last_name))
@user.subscription = subscription
@user.current_shipping_address << Address.new(address_info.merge(:country => "US"))
@user.save!
```

Comment: This doesn't work because current_shipping_address is not an array

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was that address was actually failing to save. not because of a validation but because of an error in a 'before_create' method (and yes I know I didn't give you the address object... I didn't think it important at the time!).

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relationships

  # Validators
  validates_presence_of :city, :state, :country, :first_name, :last_name, :address_1

  before_create :check_state
  before_create :check_country

  def check_state
    retval = true
    state.upcase!
    if country == "US" and !US_STATES.map{|s| s[1]}.include?(state)
      errors.add(:state, "Must be valid")
      retval = false
    end

    retval
  end
end
```

Check state was failing. But that meant that address passed the 'valid?' call, which it seems is all active record cares about. (This method really should be a validation)

I have switched to doing this (thanks enokd for the link!):

```
@user = User.new(params[:user].merge(:first_name => @address.first_name, :last_name => @address.last_name))
@user.build_subscription(:subscription_plan_id => @subscription_plan.id)
@user.build_current_shipping_address(address_info.merge(:country => "US"))
```

I haven't bothered to investigate fully, but, if address fails to save it stops the whole @user.save! 
Personally I think this is a little bit of bug perhaps or certainly an unexpected behaviour, but what do I know!

Comment: This will likely cause you more problems than you'd like.  What you should do instead of "before_create", it should be "validates".  That will give you the behavior (and failing message) if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relationships
  has_one :current_shipping_address, :class_name => "Address", :dependant => destroy
  has_many :subscriptions, :dependant => destroy

  validates :current_shipping_address, :presence => true
end
```